# Loading module error when using hpdf in lua

Tags: lua, pdf-generation

I tried to execute the following code
local hpdf = require "hpdf"

```
local pdf = hpdf.New()
if pdf then
  local page = hpdf.AddPage(pdf)
  local height = hpdf.Page_GetHeight(page)
  local width = hpdf.Page_GetWidth(page)
  local font = hpdf.GetFont(pdf, "Helvetica")
  hpdf.Page_SetFontAndSize(page, font, 24)
  hpdf.Page_BeginText(page)
  hpdf.Page_TextOut(page, 60, height - 60, "Hello from Haru")
  hpdf.Page_EndText(page)
  hpdf.SaveToFile(pdf, "hello.pdf")
  hpdf.Free(pdf)
else
  io.write("Error creating PDF object\n")
end
```

The error is
when execute the script
lua hello.lua

error
lua: error loading module 'hpdf' from file
'/usr/lib/lua/5.2/hpdf.so':
/usr/lib/lua/5.2/hpdf.so: undefined symbol:
HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile2
stack traceback:
[C]: in ?
[C]: in function 'require'
hello.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in ?

I am new to lua.Any help would appreciated?

Comment: You seem to have build libHaru without support for PNG. You need libpng for that.

Comment: I installed libpng. libHaru is working. But the error is generating when I run using LuaPDF

Comment: Use `nm -g libharu.a` and check that `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile2` appears.

Comment: See https://github.com/lhf/lhpdf-fix